# Lower headsepline

Tags: spacing, header-footer, koma-script

Is there a way to lower the headsepline? I am using koma script with the scrlayer-scrpage package. I manage my margins with

```
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the layer `scrheadings.head.below.line` using option `addvoffset=<dimension>`. If there could also be a `plainheadsepline` modify the layer `plain.scrheadings.head.below.line` too.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=5pt]{scrheadings.head.below.line}
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=5pt]{plain.scrheadings.head.below.line}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```