# KOMA scrlayer-scrpage Headmark and Image in one line

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, includegraphics, scrlayer-scrpage

Is there a way to set the headmark (name of the capter in the header) in the same height with the image?

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=10,ngerman,headings = normal,listof = totoc,bibliography = totoc,index = totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=30mm,right=30mm,top=25mm,bottom=45mm,headheight=21mm}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings} 
\clearpairofpagestyles

%\ihead{\textsc{}\\ [1ex]{\headmark}}
\ihead{\headmark}

\rohead{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1cm]{Test}}  
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\color{gray}\normalfont\small}
\begin{document} 
\chapter{no depth}
\chapter{with a g}
\end{document}
```

And with a very little margin to the headsepline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=10,ngerman,headings=normal,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,index=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=30mm,right=30mm,top=25mm,bottom=45mm,headheight=21mm}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\rohead{\raisebox{0pt}[\ht\strutbox]{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1cm]{Test}}}% <- changed
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\color{gray}\normalfont\small}% <- changed
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\begin{document} 
\chapter{test}
\chapter{with a g}
\end{document}
```

You could modify the layer with the head sepline to change its vertical position:

```latex
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=5pt]{scrheadings.head.below.line}
```

If option `plainheadsepline=true` is set, you also have to modify the layer for the `plain` style:

```latex
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=5pt]{plain.scrheadings.head.below.line}
```

Comment: Yes, it is! Thank you.

Comment: If my answer solves your issue, then you can upvote and maybe except it.

Answer (score 0):

And to change the margin of the headspline to the Text and image:

```
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=5pt]{scrheadings.head.below.line}
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=5pt]{plain.scrheadings.head.below.line}
```

Source: [Lower headsepline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334868/lower-headsepline)